# SASS & list iteration / delimiter

Tags: sass

I've got a pattern where I create a list of lists to iterate over, as an basic example:

```
$carouselContent : "carousel-content-1" "buying_carousel_image_1.jpg", 
                   "carousel-content-2" "buying_carousel_image_2.jpg";
```

My iteration (inside of a mixin) then looks like:

```
@each $carousel in $carouselContent {
  $baseClass: nth($carousel, 1);
  $image: nth($carousel, 2);
  .#{$baseClass} {
     ....
  }
}
```

I just came across a page that presently only has 1 item in the carousel. I'd like to keep with the pattern, but I'm not sure how to do so. If I iterate over:

```
$carouselContent : "carousel-content-1" "growing_carousel_image_1.jpg";
```

SASS treats that as a 2 item list. I could work around that by adding an empty item to my list, then adding a check against empty string, e.g.

```
$carouselContent : "carousel-content-1" "growing_carousel_image_1.jpg","" "";
```

But that seems hacky... so I figured there has to be a way to do this that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Are your class names really numbered like that?  Or is it just a simplified example?

Comment: Sadly, yes. I inherited this project, have a 4 week delivery time on phase II, and, despite having refactored vast swaths of it, have not refactored the carousel's yet. This is not even close to the worst offending set of class names I've come across (e.g. `#box-green { color: #699f11; } .finances #box-green { color #9370b1; }` ... #9370b1 is purple ... SMH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `@if` directive to check if the first element of your list is also a list with `type-of()` (and only then use the loop). Something along these lines (I separated the block from inside your loop as a mixin):

```
@mixin do_car($carousel) {
  $baseClass: nth($carousel, 1);
  $image: nth($carousel, 2);
  .#{$baseClass} {
    /* ... */
  }
}

@if (type-of(nth($carouselContent,1)) == list) {
  @each $carousel in $carouselContent {
    @include do_car($carousel);
  }
} @else {
  @include do_car($carouselContent);
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8477903)

Comment: this worked well. I actually moved the if conditional into a mixin, which then called a "private / internal" mixin, since I perform this operation in a dozen different SCSS files. Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 2):

In Sass 3.3.0, all you need to do is have a trailing comma to signify that what you have is a list with one item in it:

```
$carouselContent : "carousel-content-1" "buying_carousel_image_1.jpg", ;

@each $carousel in $carouselContent {
  $baseClass: nth($carousel, 1);
  $image: nth($carousel, 2);
  .#{$baseClass} {
     color: red;
  }
}
```

Generates:

```
.carousel-content-1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Sass 3.3.0 is still undergoing development, but you can play with it now by upgrading to the latest edge version via `gem install sass --pre`.  However, if you're willing to upgrade to 3.3, you may want to look at mappings instead (see: [the change log](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/doc-src/SASS_CHANGELOG.md))

Comment: yeah I can't use 3.3.0 yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If your items are numbered sequentially, you can use a for loop instead:

```
$carouselImages: 2;
@for $i from 1 through $carouselImages {
  .#{carousel-content-#{$i}} {
     background: url(buying_carousel_image_#{$i}.jpg);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.carousel-content-1 {
  background: url(buying_carousel_image_1.jpg);
}

.carousel-content-2 {
  background: url(buying_carousel_image_2.jpg);
}
```

Alternately:

```
//$carouselContent : "buying_carousel_image_1.jpg", "buying_carousel_image_2.jpg";
$carouselContent : "buying_carousel_image_1.jpg";

@for $i from 1 through length($carouselContent) {
  .#{carousel-content-#{$i}} {
     background: url(nth($carouselContent, $i));
  }
}
```

Comment: The class names are sequential, but the background image names are pretty inconsistent (we've had 3 different people slicing out the images, all with different naming conventions). There's a reason the guys on Phase I were not asked to do Phase II ... good thought though.

Comment: Actually, that can still be done.  I've added an alternate solution that allows you to have sequential class names paired with any random filename you want.

Comment: I'm not sure how to differentiate between an `@each` and `@for` as far as what the correct answer is (as I could do the same inside an `@each` loop with index), but this certainly works.

Comment: Both would give the same results.  I would expect a for/nth to perform faster than an each/index, simply because jumping to a specific index is faster than searching in other languages.