# SASS Loop to output classes with unique number and background-image

Tags: css, loops, sass

I've stumbled across a situation where a SASS loop would be great. I have a load of `<div>`'s, each one has the a unique class that follows the pattern of `.band-(number)`, a simplified version of my HTML would look like this...

```
<div class="band-1"></div>
<div class="band-2"></div>
<div class="band-3"></div>
etc.
```

Each of these elements has a unique `background-image`, but the naming convention of the image follows that of the `div`s themselves. My CSS needs to output this...

```
.band-1 {
   background-image:url('../img/image_01.png');
}
.band-2 {
   background-image:url('../img/image_02.png');
}
.band-3 {
   background-image:url('../img/image_03.png');
}
```

How would I go about outputting this in a concise way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use a for loop, incrementing a variable as you go and using something like `.band-#{$i} { ...Your styles... }`

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: I've had a read through these 2 articles - http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while / http://trulycode.com/bytes/sass-for-loop/. I can get the incrementing classes to compile, but not the background-image suffix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191714/sass-list-iteration-delimiter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve your problem with a `for` loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through 15 {
  @if $i < 10 {
    .band-#{$i} { 
      background-image:url("../img/image_0#{$i}.png");
    }
  } @else {
    .band-#{$i} { 
      background-image:url("../img/image_#{$i}.png");
    }    
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9189882)